# why do I face permission denied error in pip?

Tags: python, pip

I tried installing  a package:

```
pip install typing
```

I got this:

```
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7'
```

then I tried running it with sudo:

```
sudo pip install typing
```

and this is the error:

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

What's the error?

Is a file missing or pip not installed properly?

I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: try python -m pip install typing

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: @bluesummers this worked with sudo, it installed typing..thanks

But I got this too: The directory '/home/user_name/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: Can you `ls /usr/local/bin` and post it? It seems to me that there is a `/usr/local/bin/pip` file but it might be a dead link. In that case you can try to install pip again from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: @urban , yeah I get this:

2to3-3.4      django-admin.py   f2py3.4  gunicorn         idle3.4  _mocha  npm   __pycache__  unidecode            wagtail
chromedriver  easy_install-3.4  glances  gunicorn_django  jwt      n       pip   runxlrd.py   vagrant-lxc-wrapper
django-admin  electron          grunt    gunicorn_paster  mocha    node    pip3  sqlformat    virtualenv

Comment: Do you have 2 different versions of Python installed on your computer on two different locations?

Comment: I don't kknow about locations, but yes I have 2.7, 3.5 (by default in Ubuntu)..but I also once installed 3.4, which was not removed properly I guess

Comment: I think you have python3.4 in `/usr/local/bin` and system's python2.7 in `/usr/lib`. When you run non-sudo you use python2.7 (based on the error message you posted). When you run with `sudo` you use python3.4. To fix this either change root `$PATH` or do `sudo /usr/bin/pip install typing`

Comment: I have been able to install that module using: python -m pip install typing

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>
```

If you dont have permissions for that folder then use

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

and its always better to use ***`virtualenv`***

```
sudo pip install virtualenv <folder>
```

and for python3

```
virtualenv python3 -m venv myvenv
```

and install your package in it . `pip install typing`

Comment: i get the same error: sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory

and without sudo,  Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'

Comment: @ano_ss It is due to two versions of python. you can try it by mentioning the python version while installing  or use virtualenv python3 -m venv myvenv